# One Signal & Ionic 3: Don't show notification on specific page

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, onesignal

I have an app that receives a push notification from a server that works with One Signal. This app has a chat and every time a user sends a message to another one this one receives their notification.

It works like a charm, good, but it doesn't make any sense if a user receives a notification about a conversation which is currently opened on their device.

For example: if I'm talking to e.g. John and he sends me a message and on my device our chat is opened, I'm seeing he's just sent me a message, it doesn't look good if a push notification pops up on my phone, otherwise I'm either on another chat with another person or the app isn't opened.

I don't know if I could make myself clear, and I apologize for that, but if you got it: does it make sense and so, how to do that? I'm not seeing such a feature on One Signal docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `inFocusDisplaying` method in the init call to `None`

This will prevent all notifications from showing when the app is open.

For Ionic, documentation on this is here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--infocusdisplaying-

OneSignal does not have a way to stop notifications from displaying on only certain pages of an app.

Answer (score 0):

**for who faced this issue**

the good hack to disable notification in specific page

```js
// set it to None on page init
ngOnInit(){
  this.oneSignal.startInit("APP ID", "SENDER ID");
  this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None);
  this.oneSignal.endInit();
}

// and when this page are destroyed set it to Notification or anything else

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.oneSignal.startInit("APP ID", "SENDER ID");
    this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
    this.oneSignal.endInit();
  }
```